# Add a placeholder to search input text field

Tags: search, 9

How can I add a placeholder for the input text of the search block (*Search on my website*)?

I've looked around, but on Drupal 8 template.php has been deprecated and it's not an option.
I also need to translate the placeholder.
Copy in red is what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: On which page are you referring to ?
What theme are you using ?
A screenshot would help to get appropriate answer.

Comment: @miststudent2011 I am using Bootstrap. I only want to add a placeholder the input text in the block-search-form. The block in all pages of my website.

Comment: That is because template.php is now just (themename).theme.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help @Kevin

So I edited my (MYTHEME).theme file and added that and it works:

```
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search on my website');
}
```